# Reacting to raw input

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I am trying to write a very simple dice-game program with Python, but am running into trouble with raw_input, as I've never used it before.

```
class hand(object):    
""""
Pull three dice from cup and hold
"""
def query(self):    
    question = raw_input('Would you like to roll?')
    if question == "yes"
        print "Let's roll"
```

I want to eventually do much more advanced stuff with this; I can make a dice roll and get results but I'm trying to do it on command. I've spent hours researching raw input; most of the topics I find can shoot back a response but I need to be able to roll on command, within certain conditions.  The other topics I find put things into an array, or can simply answer a question and that's all.

Whenever I run this I get invalid syntax.  I had some other attempts as well; it would ask me the question but not respond at all when I typed 'yes'.

Comment: The semi-colon after the if statement, also indent underneath the class definiiton.

Answer (score 2):

Issues I notice in this code (none of which are related to `raw_input`):

1. If `query` is meant to be a method of the `hand` class, the entire method should be indented.
2. You need a colon after `if question == "yes"`.
3. `answer` would make more sense as a variable name than `question`, since the variable doesn't contain the question, it contains the user's answer.
4. Usual Python style uses title-case for class names, so `Hand`, not `hand`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a colon `if question == "yes":` would be correct